# Can I create procedure of mariadb in other location but mysql.proc?

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, heidisql

For security issue, I need to check whether I can create mariadb procedure in other schema, rather than mysql.proc. If it is possible, I would greatly appreciate the info and if it cannot, is there any other solid reason for it? Thank u in advance. (Mariadb version is 11.1.4)

I googled multiple times about it, but if it's my lack of description or not, I could not find any clue.

Comment: if you have privileges to create then you can create procedure or functions in any schema.. why do you think you cant create it ? just use schema_name and create it

Comment: @Adarsh, You can create a procedure in any schema, but MariaDB stores metadata about all procedures in `mysql.proc`. This cannot be changed, it's part of their implementation. I suppose the OP doesn't want users to be able to view the code of the routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedures are stored in the system table `mysql.proc` and cannot be stored elsewhere. This is just how MariaDB/MySQL works.

If you have security concerns about this, you should investigate the cause of the concern. By default, access to the mysql.proc procedure code is limited to those who created the procedure and those who have been granted access to it.

Comment: thank you, then I should consider other way round to deal with it.